# why can't pass number in JSX

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, still struggling in understanding basics. Let's say we have an User component, I want to pass props down like:

```
ReactDOM.render(<User name="Andrew" age=26/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

but it has an error, so I have to do like:

```
age='26'
```

or

```
age={26}
```

but why we can pass string but no number as the same way as string?

Comment: It's simply not how JSX works: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces `{ }` are special syntax in JSX. It is used to evaluate a JavaScript expression during compilation. A JavaScript expression can be a variable, function, an object, or any code that resolves into a value. And basically every `props` you need enclose with `"quote"` otherwise it will return an error.

Note that by using curly brackets we can insert dynamically-rendered values into our React components

You can pass any JavaScript expression as a prop, by surrounding it with `{}`.

```
<MyComponent foo={1 + 2 + 3 + 4} />
```

[JSX In Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

[Specifying Attributes with JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx).

For more help please check the link to [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) and [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/all-the-fundamental-react-js-concepts-jammed-into-this-single-medium-article-c83f9b53eac2).

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: but why I can't pass a raw integer, but passing a string is OK?

Comment: Its defined syntax for JSX. Otherwise, it will give SyntaxError: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text